# CORS POST request fails on Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, spring, google-chrome

I have a RESTfull Backend implemented with Spring security running on localhost:8080, a Login filter responds to login requests with a token placed in the headers, I didn’t even implemented an Endpoint method for that, It is all done by Spring Security magic by the following line of code:

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // disable caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();

        http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    …
```

The frontend is a Angularjs Nodejs NPM Bower project running a static http server on localhost:8000. On frontend I make a simple POST request as follows:

```
   $scope.login = function () {

    var data = {
        "username":$scope.username,
        "password":$scope.password
    }

    $http({
        url: baseUrl,
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("###### SUCCESS #####");
        var headers = response.headers();
        console.log("headers: "+JSON.stringify(headers));
        var token = headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        console.log("token: "+token);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
        $location.path("/view1");

    }, function (responseData) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns responseData with an error status.
        console.log("###### FAIL #####");
        console.log("Response: "+JSON.stringify(responseData));
        $window.alert("Failed to Login");
    });
```

This works like a charm in IE (also with curl, wget and python requests) but it miserably failing on Chrome and Safary.
I know that those Browsers are blocking CORS POSTs, making the request empty as soon as the reach the backend, in fact I don’t see any data when I log out the request from backend. I tried every possible combination of:

**Frontend side:**

1)  $http(method: POST)

2)  $http.post(

3)  Adding flags: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose, etc.

4)  Adding all possible header combination: ‘Content–Type’:’application/

**Browser side:**

1)  Start chrome with flag: --disable-web-security

2)  Installing Chrome extension CORS

**Backend side:**

1)  Spring Security Disable csfr

2)  Spring Security Permit all

3)  Spring Security HttpMethod.OPTION

**Nothing, NHOTING worked for me!**

is there something I’m missing?

Is there another way to send POST requests?

**EDIT**

As discussed, I modified the classes as follow:

WebSecurityConfig:

```
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

and implemented the CORSFilter as suggestet.

I also add the WebConfig class as suggested:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000")
        .allowedMethods("PUT", "POST");
    }
}
```

Because of the empty string the login filter throws:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input

this will be chatched by spring security which denied the access.

I also triyed to move the frontend server on other ports then 8000 (4200, 7000, etc.) with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Cors support in spring.  In your WebConfig you can override addCorsMappings

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");  //url of where angular is running.
    }
}
```

This enables cors for the whole application.  You can also be more specific with your mappings allowing specific header, and methods.

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3");
}
```

You can also allow user @CrossOrgin at the class and method level

```
@CrossOrigin(origin = "http://domain2.com",
             maxAge = 3600)
public class ApiController {

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: My webconfig is subclass of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, do I have to complete change my application structure?

Comment: That is your configuration for spring web security.  You need to create another configuration class and extend WebMvcConfigurerAdatper then override the addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registery) method.

Comment: Did it, still not working! I put the WebConfig parallel to SpringSecurityConfig, do I have to notice Spring the class is there?

Comment: denpends on how you have your application setup.  You you're using spring boot all you need is to annotate both configurations with @Configuration.  Spring will pick it up

Comment: if it still doesn't work, can you add code that you modified/added (config class) along with any errors, if any, that you're getting.

Comment: Yes I'm using springBoot, well then it is not working, thats pity!

Comment: I edited my answer with adding .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").  You may need to add the url:port of where the angular/node app is running also.  this is exactly how I have an angular2 spring boot app setup, with angular2 running on 4200 and spring boot on 8080 and it works fines.  Hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: Thanks man, your answer is correct, but to complete it can you please edit your post to add: .exposeHeaders(“header”);

Answer (score 0):

I have used a CORS filter before, and it worked well:

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

and then add this to your config:

```
.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Comment: Thanks man, but this does not work for me. I add the Filter, then add the addFilter option before loginFilter in WebConfig. It does not change anithing, CORS requests are still bloked.

Comment: You have to add it to your security config right below this `.addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` and you have to add it before `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.