# Preflight request fails on Chrome, Safary, Opera

Tags: spring-security, cors

I´m struggling with CORS requests on an Springsecurity backen project + Angulajs frontend.
CORS requests are working fine on IE (also with curl, wget and python requests) but miserably fail on Chrome and Safary because of Preflight bad request.
I know that those Browsers are blocking CORS POSTs, making the request empty as soon as the reach the backend, in fact I don’t see any data when I log out the request from backend. I tried every possible combination of:

**Frontend side:**

1)  $http(method: POST)

2)  $http.post(

3)  Adding flags: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose, etc.

4)  Adding all possible header combination: ‘Content–Type’:’application/

**Browser side:**

1)  Start chrome with flag: --disable-web-security

2)  Installing Chrome extension CORS

**Backend side:**

1)  Spring Security Disable csfr

2)  Spring Security Permit all

3)  Spring Security HttpMethod.OPTION

4)  Set up a CORS Filter that accept all origins: “*”

5)  Activated CORS framework for spring extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class.

**Nothing, NHOTING worked for me!**

I discussed this issue in another post: [CORS POST request fails on Chrome, Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972593/cors-post-request-fails-on-chrome-safari-and-firefox)
I´m still unable to perform CORS requests, this is now I major issue and I suspect the problem is in LoginFilter:

```
    public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

        private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

        public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager 

authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            ServletInputStream inputStream = httpServletRequest.getInputStream();
            httpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
            AccountCredentials credentials = null;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            credentials = mapper.readValue(inputStream, AccountCredentials.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        AccountCredentials cred = (AccountCredentials) authentication.getPrincipal();
        tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, cred);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
the exact error on Google Chrome is:

```
:8000/#!/login:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/myApp/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Comment: (1) Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43179530/edit to edit/update your question to add the exact CORS error message your browser is logging for the failed preflight. (2) Remove any frontend code you’ve added that causes any Access-Control-* headers to be added to the request. Those a Access-Control-* are all *response* headers that should only be sett on the server the request is being sent to. (3) Remove the Chrome extension CORS and do not start with -disable-web-security. Those are just going to get in the way of anybody here being able to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you control the server the cross-origin requests are being sent to? If you don’t then there is nothing you can change on your side that will allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response. (You mention you are using a Spring backend but from your question it’s not clear if that’s the backend for the web app sending the request, or whether it’s the backend for the site your code is sending the cross-origin request to.)

Comment: Hello, I´m implementig two projects, a backend running SpringBoot on port 8080 and a Frontend npm bower running a static http server on port 8000, both are set up on my local mashine, both are on domain localhost

Comment: Yes man i know thats why i put the option allow origins to "*"

Comment: The "*" not work for security reasons.

Comment: it does not work even if i set it to: http://localhost:8000

Comment: The protocol is not optional, put http:// before localhost.

Comment: it does not work even if i set it to: 1) http://localhost:8000 or 2) localhost:8000 or 3) *:8000 or 4) *:* or 5) http://*:* and all possible combination of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that it does not has ANYTHING to do with the request headers, but the problems are the response headers.

To make the preflight passing through, all response headers have to be mapped, as example:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token, Authorization, Barer, Token");
```

Answer (score -1):

The preflight request is sent AUTOMATICALLY with verb option by browser itself BEFORE the real request is sent.
You must configure your server to send response with some headers when this preflight request is sent. With spring security you can use :

```
@Provider
@Component
public class CrossDomainContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
            ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {

        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR FRONTEND URI");

        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

If you are using XML config, you can also use the `<cors />` tag.

The --disable-web-security never worked for me on Chrome. But it worked on Vivaldi Browser.

Comment: Sorry man but ContainerResponseContext class do not has addHeaders() method

Comment: Yes, it is containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(...).

Comment: Unfortunatly the request does not even pass throught the filter, do I have to add the filter to http.config?